# Java/Processing - imported objects disappear close to camera

Tags: java, processing

I've imported an object into Processing that I created in Blender.

The code below works and the object appears but seemingly very small (or distant).

If I try to move close to the object with PeasyCamm it disappears completely before it gets close enough to see properly. The only thing I could figure is that the object itself is very close to the camera but is in fact tiny...

I attempted to scale the object but a call to

```
 myshape.getVertexCount()
```

indicates my object has no vertices and nothing I do seems to change anything. I have a tiny rendered object that disappears at about a quarter of the screen height.

```
PShape myshape;

import peasy.test.*;
import peasy.org.apache.commons.math.*;
import peasy.*;
import peasy.org.apache.commons.math.geometry.*;
PeasyCam camera;

void setup(){
  size( 640, 480, P3D);
  camera = new PeasyCam(this, 0, 0, 0, 50);
  frameRate(10);
  myshape = loadShape("test.obj");
  for (int i = 0; i < myshape.getVertexCount(); i++){
      PVector v = myshape.getVertex(i);
      println("Inside");
      v.x *= 45;
      v.y *= 45;
      v.z *= 45;
      myshape.setVertex(i, v);
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);


  shape(myshape);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getVertexCount()` and `getVertex()` functions only work with shapes that you create in the code, using the `vertex()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PShape_getVertex_.html).

If all you want to do is scale your shape, then you can simply use the `scale()` function. Here is some example code that scaled your object by a factor of `20`:

```
PShape myshape;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
  myshape = loadShape("test.obj");
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(width/2, height/2, 100);
  scale(20);
  shape(myshape);
}
```

[image: scaled object]

**Edit:** Apparently you can still get to the vertexes inside an object file, it just isn't as straightforward as calling the `getVertex()` function. First you have to loop through the shape's children and then call `getVertex()` on the children. More info in [this forum post](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/comment/74561#Comment_74561) (see jeremydouglass's answer).

Comment: I've made the changes and put the code in setup. The problem is the same though.

Comment: @user3168961 What exactly is that code supposed to do, anyway? What happens if you remove it completely? Can you please post a link to your object file?

Comment: The code is supposed to display an imported object. I'm really asking why setVertex has no effect, why getVertexCount indicates zero vertices even though the object appears in my sketch (tiny)... https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlkeQFJKn27bcFtxyen14gKe4Hg

Comment: @user3168961 I'm specifically asking about the code where you're calling `setVertex()` and then multiplying the values. What is that part of the code supposed to do?

Comment: I'm trying to scale it up so the object appears larger in the processing sketch. However this code isn't ever executed and "inside" never appears (i.e. println("inside")) because a call to getVertexCount() returns 0.

Comment: @user3168961 I've edited my answer to include an approach for getting the vertexes from the file, if you need to do that in the future.